# Multiple matching conditions check in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I am having an xml like this:

```
<root>
    <p>Hellooooo world</p>
    <drawing>
        <blip embed="rId11"/>
    </drawing>
    <p>This is testing</p>
    <drawing>
      <blip embed="rId12"/>
    </drawing>
    <p>This is testing2</p>
    <drawing>
        <blip embed="rId13"/>
    </drawing>
    <p>This is testing3</p>
    <part name="/word/media/image3.png" contentType="image/png" compression="store">
        <binaryData>Test1</binaryData>
    </part>
    <part name="/word/media/image4.png" contentType="image/png" compression="store">
        <binaryData>Test2</binaryData>
    </part>
    <part name="/word/media/image5.png" contentType="image/png" compression="store">
        <binaryData>Test3</binaryData>
    </part>
    <Relationship Id="rId11" Target="media/image3.png" />
    <Relationship Id="rId12" Target="media/image4.png" />
    <Relationship Id="rId13" Target="media/image5.png" />
</root>
```

And my corresponding XSL file looks like:

```
<xsl:template match="drawing">
        <xsl:variable name="ww" select="./generate-id()"/>
        <xsl:variable name="field_id" select="//blip/@embed"/>
        <xsl:variable name="reference" select="//Relationship[@Id = $field_id]"/>
        <xsl:variable name="destination" select="//part[replace(@name,'/word/','') = $reference/@Target]"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$destination/binaryData"/>
    </xsl:template>
```

And i am getting the output as:

```
<root>   
<p>Hellooooo world</p>   
<binaryData>Test1</binaryData>
<binaryData>Test2</binaryData>
<binaryData>Test3</binaryData>
<p>This is testing</p>   
<binaryData>Test1</binaryData>
<binaryData>Test2</binaryData>
<binaryData>Test3</binaryData> 
<p>This is testing2</p>
<binaryData>Test1</binaryData>
<binaryData>Test2</binaryData>
<binaryData>Test3</binaryData>
<p>This is testing3</p>
</root>
```

After converting with the above code, i am getting repeated content and i want the similar content should be come as a result.
My expected output is:

```
<root>
<p>Hellooooo world</p>
<drawing>
<binarydata>Test1</binarydata>
</drawing>
<p>This is testing</p>
<drawing>
<binarydata>Test2</binarydata>
</drawing>
<p>This is testing2</p>
<drawing>
<binarydata>Test3</binarydata>
</drawing>
<p>This is testing3</p>
</root>
```

Can anyone please help me on this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
<xsl:variable name="field_id" select="//blip/@embed"/>
```

to

```
<xsl:variable name="field_id" select="blip/@embed"/>
```